# Grammar checker like aspell?

Tags: latex, spell-checking

I have recently started to use the program 'aspell' to spell check latex documents. I was wondering if anyone knows of a similar program to check grammar? i.e. a command line based program which will ignore latex markup.

Comment: [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) has a spell checking function, you could give it a try

Answer (score 2):

If you interact with Language Tool directly, you first need to remove markup from the file --which is very tedious. Plus, it's hard to track the errors back to your original source file afterwards.

To solve this problem, I've just finished writing a new tool for checking spelling and grammar directly on LaTeX files, called [**TeXtidote**](https://sylvainhalle.github.io/textidote):
The program can remove markup from the file and send it to the Language Tool library, which performs a verification of both spelling and grammar in a dozen languages. What is unique to TeXtidote is that it keeps track of the relative position of words between the original and the "clean" text. This means that it can translate the messages from Language Tool back to their proper location directly in your source file. TeXtidote produces an HTML report that shows your original sources, with the errors found by Language Tool highlighted at the correct location:

[image: Screenshot]

The tool is free and easy to install (OS-independent, requires Java). I encourage you to give it a try and tell me what you think!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the project [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) : LanguageTool is an Open Source proofreading program for English, French, German, Polish, and more than 20 other languages ... you can install an [extension for LibreOffice](https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-3.7.oxt) and you can download a [`.zip` file as a 'stand-alone for the desktop'](https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-3.7.zip) (you need to have Java 8 or higher installed on the operating system). More information -> [LanguageTool Wiki](http://wiki.languagetool.org/) Add-ons for Chromium and Google Chrome web browsers and for Google Docs are also available.